Django reduce number of returned rows for chart
I have model with timestamp=DateTimeField() and some extra numerical data. In table I stores data from sensor collected each minutes.
I have views returning chart with data from mentioned table which is parameterize by start_date and end_date. Chart works great for data from max few days period, but everything "explode" when period is longer (do many records).
I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I want return only n representatives records for time period (for example with avg value). I believe that my problem is common one, but I can not google ready solution for it.

The funny thing is that once people have put all the work into that, they seldomly have energy left to wrap it in a package :).

@willeM_VanOnsem - The problem is not packaging, the problem is marketing. Django solves “in-box” many problems, but we have a billion packages that do the same thing, just because the authors didn't find it in django.

@bartłomiej-bartnicki. For time series, I use the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm. Of course, it is used for GPS, but if you use linear distance instead of haversine - this algorithm works for any data on the timeline.

It's a common problem, but the primary reason there's no widely adopted package for it is that it's not easy (possibly not doable at this point in time) to create a generic, fits-common-django-databases solution.
There's a few ways you can go about it:
1. PostgreSQL: Materialized views
(a) Create a materialized view.
(b) Create an unmanaged django model:
class TimestampChart(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTime()
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False

        # This name has to match the name of the materialized view
        db_table = 'timestamp_materialized_view'

(c) Use ORM to query the view. Remember to also refresh the view (either periodically with cron or your favorite task scheduler, or on-demand using raw SQL), as PSQL doesn't do any of that automatically.
Possibly also look into django-materialized-views. I haven't tested this library, but the description seems promising.
You can engineer approaches in other SQL implementations that will look similar. For MySQL, SQLite, etc. you can build and maintain faux materialized views, but you'll have to do it manually by essentially leveraging a normal table and figuring out all the operational logic from scratch.
2. Offload select data to a specialized database with built-in tooling for this problem-category
The type of feature you're looking for is something like InfluxDB's retention policy or ElasticSearch's index lifecycle managament.
While those kinds of databases are quite powerful for these kinds of problems, the downside is that AFAIK there is no official Django support nor any widely adopted & maintained third-party package for any of them, so you might have to do the bulk of engineering yourself. The good news is that both InfluxDB and ElasticSearch have python clients, so creating ORM-like wrappers for either that you can use in your Django app should be feasible.
There are some unofficial packages that can possibly provide further help or inspiration, e.g. django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf and elasticsearch-django.
3. For smaller amounts of data, pre-process it in-memory
If your data can fit in memory, you can implement any strategy you need, whether it's downsampling, aggregation, noise cancellation or otherwise. Unless your selection algorithm becomes super complex, Python-natives alone will probably be fine.
# Downsample by slicing out only every n-th datapoint
n = 5 
res = TimestampedData.objects.order_by('timestamp')[::n]

# Aggregate by keeping only the average of every datapoint-pair
res_list = list(TimestampedData.objects.order_by('timestamp').values_list('timestamp', flat=True)

res = []
for i in range(0, len(res_list) - 1, 2):
    avg = (res_list[i] + res_list[i + 1]) / 2
    res.append(avg)

The downside here is that you'll have to run this logic every time the data is requested.
If you store this computed data and then refresh it every so often, you've essentially wandered back into creating your own faux materialized view so you should check to see if your algorithm can be implemented at the database level for a huge gain in efficiency and scalability.

I'm assuming you're using time-series database like InfluxDB for this. You can easily reduce the number of returned rows by writing a query along the following lines by using aggregation functions, e.g.
SELECT mean("field") FROM "measurement"
WHERE time >= $start AND time <= $end
GROUP BY time(1h)

